# ORA-02270 Foreign key, Can't find fault

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having a problem connecting my Sample_Measure_FK in the Sample table to the Measurement Table.

There sections of code are:

```
create table Sample
(
  Site_ID       varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Scientist_Num varchar2(7) not null,
  Comments      varchar2(4000), -- or CLOB

  constraint Sample_PK primary key (Site_ID, Recorded_On),
  constraint Sample_Site_FK foreign key (Site_ID) references Site,
  constraint Sample_Scientist_FK foreign key (Scientist_Num) references Scientist(Scientist_Num),
  -- the following is the problem:
  constraint Sample_Measure_FK foreign key (Recorded_On) references Measurement(Recorded_On)
);

create table Measurement
(
  Site_ID varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Name varchar2(50),
  Value numeric(10,8),
  Outlier_Indicator varchar2(50),

  constraint Measurement_PK primary key(Site_ID, Recorded_On),

);
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Error starting at line : 65 in command -
create table Sample
(
  Site_ID       varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Scientist_Num varchar2(7) not null,
  Comments      varchar2(4000), -- or CLOB

  constraint Sample_PK primary key (Site_ID, Recorded_On),
  constraint Sample_Site_FK foreign key (Site_ID) references Site,
  constraint Sample_Scientist_FK foreign key (Scientist_Num) references Scientist(Scientist_Num),
  constraint Sample_Measure_FK foreign key (Recorded_On) references Measurement(Recorded_On)
)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

The Other foreign keys work, but the one in bold does not.

Comment: The FK must reference the whole PK, not just one of its two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is the naming, but I would expect a single sample to have multiple measurements, suggesting that the foreign key relationship is on the wrong table:

```
create table Sample (
  Site_ID       varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Scientist_Num varchar2(7) not null,
  Comments      varchar2(4000), -- or CLOB

  constraint Sample_PK primary key (Site_ID, Recorded_On)
  constraint Sample_Site_FK foreign key (Site_ID) references Site,
  constraint Sample_Scientist_FK foreign key (Scientist_Num) references Scientist(Scientist_Num)
);


create table Measurement (
  Site_ID varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Name varchar2(50),
  Value numeric(10, 8),
  Outlier_Indicator varchar2(50),

  constraint Measurement_Sample_FK foreign key (Site_ID, Recorded_On) references Sample(Site_ID, Recorded_On),

  constraint Measurement_PK primary key (Site_ID, Recorded_On, Name)
);
```

[This does work.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1466dc)

Answer (score 1):

**The `Measurement` table needs to be created before the `Sample` table**

The foreign key is validated, so the referenced table must already exist.

**A foreign key needs to point to a primary key of another table**

> constraint Sample_Measure_FK foreign key (Recorded_On) references Measurement(Recorded_On)

Well, `Recorded_on` is not the primary key on `Measurement`. Alternatively it could be a unique constraint also, but it's not either.

You usually point foreign keys to primary keys of other tables.